# How is C++20's std::vector assign constexpr?

Tags: c++, stdvector, constexpr, c++20

Given that the current contents and size of a vector can be randomly determined at runtime, and all contents will have to be destroyed upon calling assign, how can C++20's [assign member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) be constexpr ie. compile-time?

Comment: You can have a `std::vector<T>` at compile-time (as a `constexpr` variable or inside a `constexpr` function) in C++20.

Comment: `constexpr` isn't synonymous with compile-time.

Comment: This is similar to asking: an `int` can be randomly determined at runtime, so how can an `int` be `constexpr`?

Comment: @Barry If an int is randomly assigned it's value at runtime, it is by definition, NOT constexpr.

Comment: @Justin Read the link, assign is always constexpr regardless of vector's constexpr status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-programming-at-compile-time-with-constexpr). To quote,

> Being a constexpr function does not mean that the function is executed
> at compile time. It says, that the function has the potential to run
> at compile time. A constexpr function can also run a runtime. It's
> often a question of the compiler and the optimisation level if a
> constexpr functions runs at compile time or runtime.

Ergo, unlike constexpr variables, which must be determinable at compile time, one call of a given constexpr function may run at compile time, dependent on circumstance of calling (eg. a constexpr std::vector) and another at runtime (eg. a non-constexpr std::vector).